# Constants in singleton classes

Tags: ruby, singleton, constants

I have this code:

```
class A
  def print
    puts CONSTANT
  end
end

module B
  CONSTANT = "Don't Panic!"
end
```

Suppose `a` is an instance of class A.

So I need a definition of `CONSTANT` that should be able to be found to make `a.print` available.

I considered to include the module `B` into `a`'s singleton class like:

```
a.singleton_class.send :include, B

a.print   # error: CONSTANT isn't found
```

I assumed it should be okay now to call the method but actually not.

The constant should be successfully imported as the following code works as expectation:

```
a.singleton_class.constants  # => [.., :CONSTANT, ..]
```

However, by including the constant into the **class** instead of **singleton class**, it works:

```
a.class.send :include, B

a.print   # prints: Don't Panic!
```

I thought it is strange that I can't refer a constant that is defined in a singleton class. If this is reasonable, I want to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class returned by `singleton_class` is an anonymous class which was inherited from class of the object `a`.

So `a.class` and `a.singleton_class` refer to different objects.

```
puts a.class.object_id           # => 79495930
puts a.singleton_class.object_id # => 79495830
```

And also different classes: `a.singleton_class` is a child class of `A`.

```
a.singleton_class.superclass # => A 

a.singleton_class.ancestors  # => [B, A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject] 
a.class.ancestors            # => [A, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

And because of this, `a.singleton_class` doesn't share its own constants to parent just like any other child class do.

```
puts a.class.constants             # => []
puts a.singleton_class.constants   # => [:CONSTANT]
```

Comment: Thank you at first. I got known this but it is still weird that Ruby doesn't regard constants defined in its singleton class as accessible but only class. Is this a bug, or sort of feature?

Comment: Thank you too, for interesting question. Honestly, I think it's okay. Singleton class is supposed to be inherited, anonymouse class, and this is how inheritance works - constants (or methods) which were defined in child class shouldn't appear in parent one. If we break this rule, then we lose the idea of inheritance and I'm afraid it may lead to bad design.